# linq determine if the field names in list<string> are found in selection of fields from list<Class>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of a class and a list of strings.  The list of strings contains field names that match to fields in the class.  Is there a Linq query that can determine what distinct fields are in common between the 2 lists?  See the example below.

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string Field1{get; set;}
    public decimal Field2{get; set;}
    public int Field3{get; set;}

    public ClassA(string field1, decimal field2, int field3)
    {
        Field1 = field1;
        Field2 = field2;
        Field3 = field3;
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    List<ClassA> lstClass = new List<ClassA>();
    lstClass.Add(new ClassA("value1", 1.23, 1));
    lstClass.Add(new ClassA("value2", 0.32, 3));
    lstClass.Add(new ClassA("value3", 2.34, 9));

    List<string> lstNames = "Field1,Field2".ToString().Split(',').ToList();

    // How to find intersection using linq of lstClass and lstNames (should be list  containing Field1 and Field2).
}
```

A second followup question is how to get the list of fields from lstClass (should be list of strings containing "Field1", "Field2", and "Field3").

Thanks,

Lee

Comment: Not clear. Can you make it clear? Sample input and expected output would be better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

```
    typeof(ClassA).GetProperties(
       BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .ToList() // Returns all the public instance properties of ClassA
```

So your solution:

```
var lstFieldNames = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties(
       BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
       .Select(p=>p.Name).ToList()

var intersect = lstFieldName.Intersect(lstNames);
```

Comment: That worked great. Is there a way to get the values along with the names in the intersection?

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of intersection:

```
var lstFieldNames = typeof(ClassA).GetProperties(
       BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
       .Select(p=>p.Name).ToList()

var intersect = lstFieldName.Intersect(lstNames);
var type = typeof(ClassA);
var myObject = new ClassA(); // or any other object you want its properties values
var values = intersect.Select(p => new {
           Name = p,
           Value = type
                  .GetProperty(p, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public)
                  .GetValue(myObject, null)
           });
```

Comment: This looks like it will work - but I have an added complication. I am in a generic method so cannot get myObject.  How would I be able to determine myObject and consequently values?

Comment: You must be in a place where you can access some object to extract its value(s). Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sure-I have a method as follows: public object[,] ExtractObjectArrayFromList<T>(List<T> lstData, List<string> lstColumns). lstData has the data but could be from ClassA, ClassB, etc. lstColumns is the list of column names. Without having to loop through every row of lstData (as I am doing now), I wish to get the intersection as you have provided. I need the values as well though to place into the result. I am hoping to get an IEnumerable result containing the field names and the field values which I can then loop through and place in a object array. I can send a snippet if neccessary.

Comment: Do you only need the values of the objects of type ClassA?

Comment: Would the values match the order of the field names? If so, that would be fine. Essentially I am trying to get a subset of lstData that has all of its rows, but only the columns specified. The values need to match the field names though.

Comment: You'll get a list of an anonymous type having two properties: Name and Value which bears the value of the matching property.